# Android phonegap splashscreen from external storage

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, android-external-storage

I am able to show splashscreen from drawable folder in my phonegap app using the code as follows:

```
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

But what if, I want to load image for splashscreen from sdcard or internal storage.

As, I am loading the data from the server using my external storage, and after the data being loaded, I want the image from that data to be used as a splashscreen.

What method or property should I use in that case, as I cannot directly use super.setIntegerProperty(), as it requires integer parameter for splashscreen, but what I have is only the path to that sdcard image.

A similar query is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098602/android-splash-screen-image-from-sd-card), but the answer doesn't seem suitable to me.